# add graph items to existing graph in zabbix using API's

Tags: python, api, graph, zabbix

I have a graph created in zabbix. I want to update this graph to include items from other hosts. For that I am calling graph.update() zabbix API using a python script. The method is updating the graph item instead of adding/appending to the existing graph item list. Does any one has idea about this ?
`graph.update(graphid=graph_id,gitems=[{"itemid" :"10735", "color":"26265b"}])`
where `graph_id` is and id of existing graph.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Get the existing graph items with `graph.get` first, then update the graph and pass all the existing items (include `gitemid` for these items) with your new items added.

Comment: graph.get() method gives me one item having `gitemid`. After this how should I write graph.update() method to add `gitemid` for other items and what value should be given to `gitemid`?

Comment: Only specify gitemid for the one existing item - leave it off for the new items, they will get an ID assigned automatically.

Comment: I didn't get it Richlv. Can you please share the graph.update command?

Comment: please show the data (preferably raw JSON) that you send to Zabbix, describe what happens and what you want to happen instead.